# How to get id attribute value in twig if condition for comparision

Tags: javascript, html, twig

Working on twig Html language

```
<select id="input-custom-field{{ custom_field.custom_field_id }}" onchange="{% if this.id == 'input-custom-field1' %} myFun(){% endif %}" >
```

The above line is in Twig html.How to get the value of id attribute under if condition? You may see i have already set the id value input-custom-field{{ custom_field.custom_field_id }} which return "input-custom-field1". i want to use this value as a left string in if statement because if this statement return true then assign myFun() in onchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all data to do this. You can use `custom_field.custom_field_id` as a left-side value in the condition

```
<select id="input-custom-field{{ custom_field.custom_field_id }}" onchange="{% if custom_field.custom_field_id == 1 %} myFun(){% endif %}" >
```

Comment: Thanks... Sometimes things are easy but we think more and that's why  we don't get solution..